# redirect to mobile using browser width instead of screen width

Tags: javascript, mobile

Im looking to redirect my site to a mobile version by detecting the browser width as oppose to `screen.width`, is this possible?
Here is the code I want to change...

```
<script type="text/javascript">


<!--
if (screen.width <= 767) {
    window.location = "http://m.mysite.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

`screen.width` doesnt seem to give a reliable response as the resolution is so high on mobiles (I think this is the issue). so then when I set the figure higher it starts loading up the mobile site on Ipads or small desktop browsers.

Id rather not go down the user agent route due as I dont want to have to be checking every site every time a new handset gets released.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are missing a definition of "mobile". What is mobile for you? Is it all devices that run Android or iOS? Do you determine the screen width or size to determine if it is mobile? Are touch devices considered as mobile? You will have to define what is "mobile" for you first before seeking for solutions.

Comment: I would consider mobile an average sized handset that you can make calls on, so android and ios alone wouldnt be accurate enough (because of tablets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with this problem, but to help you, I googled a little bit around, I found some articles which may be of use to you, they include PHP, Javascript and some documentation about how & why.

Maybe you'll find it usefull.

1 :

http://twoninewebdesign.com/2012/01/Admin/mobile-device-redirect-for-your-website/

2 :

http://mobithinking.com/guide-device-detection

3 :

http://www.webhostinghub.com/support/website/how-to/mobile-redirect

Sincerly,
Harmen Brinkman.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go for a combination of user agent, screen width and window width. This should make it as accurate as possible.

I used the PHP code from here... http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ 
And edited my javascript a little..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
<!--

if (screen.width <= 767 || windowWidth <= 767) {
    window.location = "http://m.mysite.com";
}
//-->
</script>
<?php //CODE FROM LINK ABOVE ?>
```